# macのSSHでの「too many authentication」対策

Tags: macos, ssh

macのターミナルで秘密鍵でサーバーにログインするとき、
予め　ssh-add　にて秘密鍵を登録しておき、

ssh -i ~/.ssh/user.rsa user@0.0.0.0

にて接続しています。

しかし、これらのサーバーは５０近く管理しているため（実際は５つ程度登録しただけで）、次第に
「too many authentication」というエラーが出てしまうため、
ssh-add -D　で登録したものを全部削除して、接続するものだけ登録
ということを繰り返しています。

どうして　too many authentication　が出るのでしょうか？
sshコマンドではRSAファイルのパスを指定しているのでそのファイルでログインすればいいのになんでssh-addしたファイルをすべて使ってログインしようと試みるのでしょうか？

対策はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSHのsshは-iや.ssh/configのIdentityFileで鍵を指定しても先にssh-agentに登録されてる鍵での認証を試行します。.ssh/configでIdentitiesOnlyをyesにすることで、指定した鍵での認証を強制する事ができます。

鍵を指定したらそれを先に使うのが素直な動きに見えるんですが、なんでこういう挙動になっているのかはよくわかりません。

余談ですが、接続先毎に違う鍵を使うのはセキュリティ的にはあまり意味がありません。秘密鍵が1つ漏れたのなら、同じ場所にある他の秘密鍵もすべて漏れたと想定すべきです。その場合の鍵の無効化の事まで考えると、漏れが出やすい分かえって有害かもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございました

なるほど！　意味がありません〜　の件も了解です！
言われてみれば全くそのとおりですね
管理するサーバーごとにクライアント端末を分けるわけじゃないので
一緒ですね！むしろデメリットだと

Comment: -iでの認証鍵ファイル指定は、エージェントにアクセス可能な時はそのエージェントに登録されている鍵のなかでどれを使うかの選択に利用されます。-iで指定した鍵がエージェントにあればまずそれを使うというようにですね。なので最初の質問のように利用する鍵がエージェントに登録されていればtoo many authenticationにはならないはずなので、なんで質問者の環境ではエラーになるのかちょっと疑問に思いますが。

Answer (score 1):

`ssh -v`で詳細のログを出すと何かわかるかもしれません。まずは下記のオプションをお試しください。

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/user.rsa 'IdentitiesOnly yes' user@0.0.0.0
```